# Connect to Freenode using tor

Tags: irc, tor, xchat

My proxy blocks the connection to IRC. But to my surprise freenode doesn't accept connections from tor network.

I added the onion address in Xchat as FreenodeOverTor in the network list.

I installed SASL plugin in Xchat. Used the command

/sasl -set FreenodeOverTor nick passwd

However I am unable to connect. What to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script I downloaded was buggy. I asked at freenode using qwebirc, they helped me and it worked!!!

Thanks All.

Comment: Sharing your solution in detail with us would be nice for the people which might find this answer over a search-machine.

Answer (score 2):

My thinking is that your SASL is probably not working. Check that SASL is working independent of Tor (you can use SASL auth when connecting over clear Internet) and once you get that down, try bringing Tor in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Freenode blocks tor very actively, since it can be easily abused. There is no existing work around that I know of, and even then they will probably get blocked.

Have you tried non-standard ports? Freenode accepts connections over 8000-8002 and SSL over 7000 and 7070. If they block access to the url irc.freenode.net, try direct connecting to servers listed [here](http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml).

Comment: I did same as mentioned here http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml#tor and http://www.beuc.net/tor/

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a (VERY detailed) HOWTO on how to connect your irc client to Tor and authenticate with SASL to Freenode's Tor nodes. You can see that here:

http://blog.gnu-designs.com/howto-configure-tor-sasl-irc-to-connect-to-freenode

There's plenty of other useful posts, HOWTOs and posts on my blog that you might be able to use.

Use the Search Luke! :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.