# IRC newbie needs detailed "How To" directions for freenode.net connection with OS X IRC app

Tags: macos, irc, colloquy, freenode

Newbie IRC user here.  Trying to get connected on freenode.net, preferably with a native Mac OS X client (I'm running 10.6.8), or at least something with a good "OS X feel."  Also seeking a client that comes "well regarded" in Mac community (eg, Linkinus reflects outstanding Apple App Store user ratings).  Thus far have found it remarkably difficult to "get started from scratch" with ANY client.  All attempted clients (Colloquy, Textual, Linkinus) experience some sort of "*** Notice -- You need to identify via SASL to use this server" error.  I see this [freenode SASL-friendly client list](http://freenode.net/sasl/README.txt); am I really limited to only these clients?

This "IRC-freenode startup" procedure has been far more difficult than I had originally anticipated.  Why can't I just [do this](https://superuser.com/questions/220245/how-do-i-register-a-nickname-on-freenodes-irc-network-using-colloquy) and have it "just work"?

Bottom line: looking for a "chapter and verse"/cookbook description of how to get started with freenode.net IRC chat rooms on Mac OS.  Need reference to known-working client, and then exact directions on how to get connected to a chat room with a nickname.

Comment: Also prefer to freenode-connect with a bona fide "app" instead of a web-page client, presumably affording me benefits like session logging/archiving to my own storage space (on my MacOSX machine), multiple chat-room connections, automatic logins, and possibly other benefits not yet realized (by me).

Comment: fwiw. Here's a [superuser.com discussion/list of MacOSX IRC clients](http://superuser.com/questions/20440/mac-os-x-irc-clients).

Comment: [This discussion](http://superuser.com/questions/166909/connect-to-freenode-using-tor) seems to cover similar ground.  [This post](http://superuser.com/questions/166909/connect-to-freenode-using-tor/263732#263732) looks particularly promising.

Answer (score 1):

I use Adium for IRC on freenode it's fairly easy to setup plus you can configure other IM Chat protocols. You can just add the join channel commands etc under options when setting up the account.

http://adium.im/

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [xchat aqua](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xchataqua/) - most flavours of xchat have freenode preconfigured. Once you've connected to the server, you can use /msg nickserv register to register a nick.

Screenshots from a windows build but they ALL work the same, so they will work.

Most xchat builds seem to be preconfigured to go to a specific channel on freenode, and have a bunch of channels added. Normally it will pop up a network list window (alternately this is under xchat -> network list ). At this point fill in your preferred nick, two alternates and a username and another name. check if freenode is on your default user list, and clock on edit. That will open the edit server window (to the right) - if it isn't hit the + button, create a new server option and fill in the data as below. Any options here will override the global settings, so you can set a per server username.

Add the channels you want to autoconnect to under favourite channels (they will normally be called #something) . Leave the nickserv password blank. Click close and connect.

[image]

Once connected, you will want to register your nickname. Assuming it isn't already registered by someone, you can register the nickname you have now with the command `/msg nickserv REGISTER password email`

Now go back to the network list and add your password under nickserv password to automatically use that password.

Now that that works, you can turn on logging if it isn't already under 'preferences -> logging'. If you want to connect to a server without it being on your network list, you can use `/server servername` and join channels not on autoconnect with `/join #channelname`

Let me know if there's anything else i need to add, and i'll update the answer.